# How to change architecture of .ipa or .app from arm64 to i386 without source code

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin.uitest

I'm writing mobile autotests using C#, Xamarin 6.1.3, iOS 10.2, iPhone 6s Plus, Xcode 8.2, OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. 
I'm trying to launch tests on simulator using the following command:

```
IApp iApp = ConfigureApp.iOS.AppBundle(path_to_app/Application.app).StartApp();
```

I've got the following error:

```
Calabash.XDB.Core.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : Failed to install app /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/new2/Payload/Atom.app

ExitCode: 5

    -a,--app-bundle <path/to/app-bundle.app>    Path .app bundle (for .ipas, unzip and look inside of 'Payload')
    -c,--codesign-identity  <codesign-identity> [OPTIONAL]  Identity used to codesign app bundle [device only]  DEFAULT=
    -d,--device-id  <device-identifier> iOS Simulator GUIDs
    -u,--update-app <true-or-false> [OPTIONAL]  When true, will reinstall the app if the device contains an older version than the bundle specified DEFAULT=1
install
Error installing org.gamatech.Movie-Friends to 9E44D0FE-A3F9-4FC1-8635-    20FB8AD20BA4: Error Domain=com.facebook.FBSimulatorControl Code=0 "Simulator does not support any of the architectures ([arm, arm64]) of the executable at /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/new2/Payload/Atom.app/Atom. Simulator Archs ([x86_64, i386])" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator does not support any of the architectures ([arm, arm64]) of the executable at /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/new2/Payload/Atom.app/Atom. Simulator Archs ([x86_64, i386])}
false

at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchAppLocal (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Boolean clearAppData) [0x0020a] in <e747267e258a4a668973c7ca7e9014a8>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Xamarin.UITest.TestCloud.TestCloudiOSAppConfiguration testCloudAppConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient testCloudWsClient, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient xtcServicesClient, System.Boolean testCloudUseDeviceAgent) [0x0007a] in <e747267e258a4a668973c7ca7e9014a8>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00302] in <e747267e258a4a668973c7ca7e9014a8>:0 
at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in <e747267e258a4a668973c7ca7e9014a8>:0 
at Xamarin.Application.Initialize () [0x00026] in /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/Xamarin/Application.cs:44 
at Xamarin.Application..ctor () [0x00011] in /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/Xamarin/Application.cs:22 
at Xamarin.Application.GetInstance () [0x0000c] in /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/Xamarin/Application.cs:62 
at Xamarin.BaseTest.InitBeforeTest () [0x0000b] in /Volumes/Win7 Ultim/Framework/Xamarin/BaseTest.cs:18 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

Ios simulator supports only i386 architecture, as I know it cannot be changed.
**Is it possible to change architecture of application, if I don't have source code, just `.ipa` and `.app` files?**

Comment: Normally the app needs to be built with the appropriately supported architecture, I'm not sure if it's possible to change the architecture after the app is built. Where are you getting the app from, directly from the author, or someplace else like the app store?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the supported architecture of an `.ipa` or an `.app` without the source code.